# Best way to handle long press for multiple objects in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, long-press

I have a view with 64 UIButtons that need to respond to a long press in addition to their touch up event. I thought I could easily do this by creating a UILongPressRecognizer in my xib, conect all the buttons to the recognizer in a outlet collection, then test for the button's tag in the handler. Here I have the first 3 buttons wired...

[image]

And here is my handler...

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%i", sender.view.tag);

}
```

The buttons are tagged from 1-32 and 101-132, but I only get the the tag for the first button in the collection. If the first button is tag 1 then all three will return 1 in the handler, if I wire them from 3 to 1 the handler gets 3 as the tag for all three buttons.

All the buttons have the same title which as you can see is a period. I would not think that this would make any difference.

How can I handle the long presses for each button without creating 64 longPressRecognizers?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Have not yet figure out how to use the tag value of the buttons, so I am moving on using the posiion of the long press instead. Would still like to know how to do it using the button tags, if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
 CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:screenView];
```

to check button was pressed or not.

Comment: Thnks, but I wanted to use something other than the tap location as the locations may change in the future. Tags seemed to be the only possibility. Based on my google searches and the lack of response to this posted question, it looks like working with the position is my only option.

Comment: What is the value of [sender tag] instead of sender.view.tag?

Comment: sender is a UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan which does not have a tag property so [sender tag]  will throw an unrecognized selector exception. Only it's view has a tag property.

Comment: Obvioualy I meand to say UIGestureRecognizer.